# Duplicate layer using Control button on keyboard

Tags: qgis, layers

I noticed in QGIS 2.14 I can hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and drag to duplicate a layer. But this seems to create a copy linked from source layer. Unlike if I use "Duplicate" in context menu this procedure reflects any modification (or rename) on both layers.

Does anyone know more about this feature? Or some way to identify a duplicated or linked layer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite shure what the practical use of the Ctrl-drag feature is, but a way to distinguish duplicated from linked layers is the layer_id which is the same for linked layers and differs for duplicated layers (layer properties, see the variables-tab).

[image]